# ListView didn't show

Tags: android, listview

i want to use a simple list view, but when i run my program, i get ERROR.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.list);

         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         String[] values = new String[]{"Number 1", "Number 2", "Number 3"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, "Click ListItem Number " + position
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

now, can you tell me where is my problem??

Update : 
my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.animeparadise"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AnimeParadiseT1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_anime_paradise_t1" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_anime_paradise_t1" android:name=".ViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_anime_paradise_t1" android:name=".AboutActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_anime_paradise_t1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

logCat :

```
09-04 16:04:23.485: D/dalvikvm(7779): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 46K, 51% free 2686K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 67ms
09-04 16:04:25.917: D/AndroidRuntime(7779): Shutting down VM
09-04 16:04:25.917: W/dalvikvm(7779): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40195560)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.animeparadise/com.animeparadise.ListViewActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at com.animeparadise.AnimeParadiseT1$1.onClick(AnimeParadiseT1.java:30)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-04 16:04:25.927: E/AndroidRuntime(7779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have run your code it is working fine. please paste manifest file.

Comment: Yeah for me to. It works fine. Do a Project->Clean maybe

Comment: look, this is not my whole program. my manifest is big. but i update it.

Comment: Try extending ListActivity instead of just Activity.

Comment: look at my logcat, maybe it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `"<activity android:name=".ListActivity" to ".ListViewActivity"` in your Manifest file.

There is your error.....

Comment: Extend ListActivity instead of just Activity in your java code and then try this. It should work.

Comment: it work. i just changed it to listActivity. now i change it to Activity and it work. tnx for help.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot find out who gave you the negative vote in SO. sry abt that.

Comment: yes i know. but it's not so important. i wanted an answer. now i have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Try this.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `fill_parent` in width and height of `LinearLayout` and in width of `ListView`.

EDIT after seeing you Manifest.
You have an Activity named ListViewActivity, yet you declared:

```
<activity android:name=".ListActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_anime_paradise_t1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Changed it to `ListViewActivity`, and second: The intent-filter with MAIN and LAUNCHER should only be for the first `Activity` which is shown at start-up for you app.